# How to change the bootstrap nav bar to take up the full width and get rid of the rectangle at the left?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[nav bar on my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21vmT.jpg)

I'm working on a project using angular and bootstrap following a tutorial. I'm new to web development. I used the nav bar in the project. I got the code from Bootstrap website. However, the nav bar doesn't look good.

There are two problems.

1. The elements on the nav bar are squeezed together. They do not take up the full width of the page. How can I make it take up the full width?
2. There is a rectangle button at the left, next to the title. How can I hide it when the nav bar is not collapsing?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the html code.

```html
  <div class="container" >
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{title}}</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Problem">
          </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

          <li>
            <form class="navbar-form">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
            </form>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{username}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Favorites</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">My Submissions</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Log Out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Try right clicking the whitespace and doing inspect element. It can really help when figuring out why things look the way they do.

Comment: Is it because I didn't do the configuration right? Something about the dependency? JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the bootstrap version to 3.3.7. Now everything looks fine. I have tried 4.1.0, but it didn't work well neither. I don't exactly know what's the matter under the hood. At least, the nav bar is working now.